# Calling attribute of class via for loop causes an error

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code below

```
class attsClass():
    def __init__(self,aw,ax,ay,az):
        self.aw = aw
        self.ax = ax
        self.ay = ay
        self.az = az
ac = attsClass('W','X','Y','Z')
ac.ax
```

here I will get the result which is 'X',but if i call like how i did below we get an error

```
att_names = ['aw','ax','ay','az']
for att in att_names:
    print(ac.att)
```

here I can't access the attribute

only with this can I access it

```
att_names = ['ax','ay','az']
for att in att_names:
    print(att, getattr(ac, att))
```

can someone explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first example gets the `att` attribute of `ac`, which doesn't exist. Variables are not used to resolve attribute names.

When you call `getattr`, you're passing the variable to a Python function that is able to dynamically read attributes. Since the variable is an argument here, it is resolved.